# Avoid possible symlinks in C++ when using ofstream

Tags: c++, security, file-io, flawfinder

I have this code

```
    ofstream file;
    file.open(filePath, std::ios::app);    
    file << content;
    file.close();
```

When I run `Flawfinder` it says:

```
[2] (misc) open:
  Check when opening files - can an attacker redirect it (via symlinks),
  force the opening of special file type (e.g., device files), move things
  around to create a race condition, control its ancestors, or change its
  contents? (CWE-362).
```

My question: is there any better/safer way to write the same code above to deal with files in order to avoid such possible security vulnerabilities?

Comment: Note that you should ask this **c++** realted question in [**c++ section**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) instead of [**c section**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

Comment: Things like `lstat()` and `std::filesystem::symlink_status()` can tell you if the filename refers to a symlink before you try to open it.